# How to accept permission for getUserMedia() in jasmine testing?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing an AudioRecorder class whose init() accesses Navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).

Is there a way to accept the user permission request in the DOM from Jasmine?

Source:

```
export default class AudioRecorder {
  async init() {
    const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream)
  }
```

Jasmine test:

```
it('init()', done => {
    const record = new AudioRecorder();

    record.init().then(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: You could write a polyfill for MediaRecorder so that init immediately does a `Promise.resolve()`.

Here's a polyfill that might work, but easy enough to just roll your own.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371404/how-to-accept-permission-for-getusermedia-in-jasmine-testing

Answer (score 1):

You should be spying on `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, forcing it to return a promise and resolving it with the value that you want.

You can put something like this in a `beforeEach` block, or at the beginning of the test:

```
const audioStream = { ... }; // create a mock audio stream with the appropriate methods spied on
let promise = Promise.resolve(audioStream);
spyOn(navigator.mediaDevices, 'getUserMedia', promise);
```

I'd also recommend that you convert your test to async, like this:

```
  it('init()', async done => {
    const record = new AudioRecorder();
    const result = await record.init();
    // test something with the result of init
    done();
  });
```

I think it is much easier to follow the control flow here.